# WebClient.DownloadData(uri) HTTP NTLM Authentication fails with 401 using correct credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have the following code:

```
using (WebClient wcli = new WebClient())
{
    wcli.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    wcli.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("RS_Username", "RS_Password", "RS_Domain");

    byte[] buff = wcli.DownloadData(www);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + reportName + ".pdf\"");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(buff);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

I use it get the result of a report in SSRS 2014 and have it as a document download from my web application (in .Net 3.5, hosted on Window 8.1, IIS 8.5).

The problem I have is that I keep getting *401 Unauthorized* when calling `wcli.DownloadData(www)` (Note the using any browser the reports are working fine with the credentials used)
I have done a TCP Dump and I have found out that the NTLM handshake is not occurring:

1. C -> S: GET Request
2. C <- S: '401 Unauthorized' response with header
   'WWW-Authenticate: NTLM'
3. *Nothing else*

Another application hosted on the same machine but using .Net 4.5 uses the same code without any problem.

I believe it has to be due to a missing/wrong configuration, but I do not succeed to figure out which one.
Any ideas?

### UPDATE

What I have forgotten to mention is that both web applications mentioned (both hosted on the same server and IIS) are connecting to the same Reporting Services server (but different folders).

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue, in my case (Still .Net4.5) what worked was to use:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();  
wc.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
string host = "http://localhost"; //this comes from a function in my code
var myCredentialCache = new System.Net.CredentialCache();
myCredentialCache.Add(new Uri(host + "/"), "NTLM", new System.Net.NetworkCredential(accessUser, accessPassword, domain));

wc.Credentials = myCredentialCache;

var result = wc.DownloadFile(www);
```

The main diference for me was to use a CredentialCache and setting the host uri, also the domain in the network credential

Answer (score 0):

You're telling the WebClient to use the DefaultCredentials. `wcli.UseDefaultCredentials = true;` but you're also passing in a NetworkCredential. Perhaps the other code that works, if they're both using the same code, is working because it's user has access.

```
using (WebClient wcli = new WebClient())
{
    wcli.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    wcli.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("RS_Username", "RS_Password", "RS_Domain");
}
```

However, that may not be your bug. Came across this article: http://www.benjaminathawes.com/2010/10/14/ntlms-dependency-on-http-keep-alives-another-cause-of-the-dreaded-401-1-error/.

It mentions the need to use HTTP keep-alive to keep the TCP connection open for the NTLM handshake. The fact that the handshake just dies leads me to think that maybe that could also be the issue. I would check to verify that keep-alive is indeed on.

Comment: The keep-alive setting in matter is on by default.

Comment: I am just wondering if it is not related to the IIS Application Pools used as the .Net 4.5 application uses the '.Net 4.5' pool whereas the .Net 3.5 application (for which it fails) uses the 'Classic .Net AppPool'.

Comment: You could try that. But if they're under different app pools, then it might be the user. Is the user different for the two app pools?

Comment: I would look at the user. As I mentioned your code says to use the default user. So see if you change the user to the same user as the one that works what happens.

Comment: Based on the [WebClient source code](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/Net/System/Net/webclient@cs/1305376/webclient@cs), `WebClient.UseDefaultCredentials=true` only pre-set `WebClient.Credentials` to `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`, which is then overwritten by `new NetworkCredential("RS_Username", "RS_Password", "RS_Domain")`. **NB**: I tried only using `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` while trying to figure out the cause and the result was _403 Forbidden_